# Group conversation in Facebook chat

Tags: facebook-groups, facebook-messenger

I have a conversation group that shows up on my Facebook chat but, there never was a group chat and it cannot, as far as I know, be erased.

How do you erase it?

I already checked instant messaging and there is nothing.

Can other people see this group?

Answer (score 1):

The same thing is showing up on my chat. The only thing I found or was able to do so far is hide the group conversation. Click on the Chat options and select Hide groups. At least you won't see them. Not sure why it's doing that but at least the names of the friends in the group chat also show in the individual chat. :)

Answer (score 0):

group chat is usually created by admin who managed the groups and they can add the friends as per their wishes.To remove from the group chat,

(i) You can go to the conversation of the group  and click on cogwheel icon
(ii)Now select Leave conversation.This would remove from the group chat and it would be notified.

If you send message,All the participant in the group can be able to view.